# Can't clear up space on macOs Catalina. "Other" takes 370GB out of 500GB and other tools show half of this

Tags: macos, disk, macos-catalina, recycle-bin

Recently I had almost full disk space taken on my Macbook Pro running macOs Catalina. I saw that what took most of my space was folder under: **/Users/Shared/Relocated Items** so I deleted this folder by moving to trash and emptying it. I deleted many other files as well.

I thought I just got 200 GB free disk space. But not at all!:

**About screenshot**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Disk-utility Screenshot**

[image: Screen Shot]

Only my "Other" size increased to 417GB! Which is insane. And what's more when I run sizing in software like **OmniDiskSweeper** or **DiskInventoryX** I get 179.5GB taken only!:

**OmniDiskSweeper Screenshot**

[image: Screen Shot]

And the same in DiskInventoryX. And before cleaning it was showing the same size taken as MacOs.

What is going on here? I tried:

- Running in recovery mode and running first aid on my disk.
- I have never enabled Time Machine. I ran some commands for delete backups and it appeared I didn't have any

When I delete some file the "Other" area just gets bigger and I can't get rid of it.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: This is in the wrong place. Stack Overflow is for programming questions only. It belongs on the AskDifferent Stack Exchange site.

Comment: While @MarkSetchell is probably right. How big is your data volume? `Machintosh HD - Data`

Comment: What does it say if you in finder `Go to > Computer` and right click `Machintosh HD` and see what `Show info` says?

Answer (score 1):

DiskUtil will only show the your primary volume. To see all volumes on the disk you can try "View" > "Show All Devices" and then click up one level to view the device that hosts your HD volume.

Alternately open a terminal and run `diskutil list` to show all volumes, it may be your recovery volume spiked with the deletions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the question [Storage only shows “Other” + Fluctuating storage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136591/storage-only-shows-other-fluctuating-storage) on AskDifferent, the issue you're experiencing might be related to a corrupted Spotlight index.

You could try [rebuilding the Spotlight index](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83958/spotlight-doesnt-work-anymore-in-os-x-mountain-lion) using those commands:

```
sudo mdutil -i off /
sudo mdutil -E /
sudo mdutil -i on /
```

It might take a while to rebuild.

Also, [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) has functionality related to finding hidden storage on your Mac. There is a trial available. 
Alternatively, you could also try the free [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net) to check your disk usage.